# MySQL and index on sum

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing

I've got a table with some data. For simplicity it looks like:

```
id - auto_increment
c1 - int
c2 - int
created - date
```

There might be lots of  data

The way I get the data is such:

`SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) ORDER by c1 + c2 DESC LIMIT 10`

How to make index for c1 + c2? Is it possible? Should I add it, I mean will it slow the query?

Comment: You want to order by the sum of c1 and c2 columns or do you want to order by both columns?

Comment: @bonCodio, I want sum of these columns

Comment: @Dave, what do you mean?

Comment: @arthur.borisow - you've accepted only 35% of the answers to questions you've asked.  This is usually an indication that you don't care or don't follow through.  You should accept correct answers to questions you've asked in the past to get your "accepted rate" higher.

Answer (score 0):

The only index that is useful for

```
SELECT *            -- I assume many fields here
    FROM my_table
    WHERE created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR) -- useful
    ORDER by c1 + c2 DESC   -- expressions cannot be indexed
    LIMIT 10         -- does not matter
```

is

```
INDEX(created)
```

For more discussion on creating the optimal index, see my [index cookbook](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql).

Hot off the press:  5.7 can create and index materialized virtual columns, such as `(c1+c2)`.  Hence, a composite index starting with that col and ending with `created` *might* be better in 5.7.

Answer (score -1):

You can just create a index with both fields.
Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD INDEX sumC1C2 (c1,c2)
```

Comment: I don't understand the negative. If you have an index for both, to fetch the values will be faster and then it will be less performance problems.

Comment: Not me downvoting, but I suspect the index won't make much (positive) difference. The query can filter on `created` to filter the number of rows down, but then has to pick the values out of the index row by row to do the sum anyway (the index isn't on the sum, but on the parts), most likely not faster than just doing it out of the table right away.